# ElementRef.inner_html() escapes HTML

Tags: web-scraping, rust

I am writing a web scraper using `rslint_parser` "0.3.1" and `scraper` "0.16.0".
I encountered the issue that `scraper::ElementRef::inner_html()` returns the HTML text escaped. Here is a minimal example of the issue:

`./src/lib.rs`

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use rslint_parser::{parse_text, SyntaxNodeExt};
use scraper::{ElementRef, Html, Selector};

const JS_TOKENS: [&str; 2] = ["myJSON", "="];
static SCRIPT_SELECTOR: Lazy<Selector> =
    Lazy::new(|| Selector::parse("script").expect("could not build script selector"));

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum ScrapingError {
    JSONNotFound,
    ScriptElementNotFound,
}

pub fn extract_json_1(script: ElementRef) -> Result<String, ScrapingError> {
    for element in parse_text(&script.inner_html(), 0).syntax().children() {
        let tokens = element.tokens();

        if tokens
            .iter()
            .take(2)
            .zip(JS_TOKENS)
            .all(|(token, name)| token.text() == name)
        {
            if let Some(json_tokens) = tokens.get(2..tokens.len() - 1) {
                return Ok(json_tokens
                    .iter()
                    .map(|token| token.text().as_str())
                    .collect());
            }
        }
    }

    Err(ScrapingError::JSONNotFound)
}

pub fn extract_json_2(script: ElementRef) -> Result<String, ScrapingError> {
    for element in parse_text(&script.text().collect::<String>(), 0)
        .syntax()
        .children()
    {
        let tokens = element.tokens();

        if tokens
            .iter()
            .take(2)
            .zip(JS_TOKENS)
            .all(|(token, name)| token.text() == name)
        {
            if let Some(json_tokens) = tokens.get(2..tokens.len() - 1) {
                return Ok(json_tokens
                    .iter()
                    .map(|token| token.text().as_str())
                    .collect());
            }
        }
    }

    Err(ScrapingError::JSONNotFound)
}

pub fn find_script(html: &Html) -> Result<ElementRef, ScrapingError> {
    match html
        .select(&SCRIPT_SELECTOR)
        .find(|element| element.value().attr("id") == Some("my_script"))
    {
        Some(element) => Ok(element),
        None => Err(ScrapingError::ScriptElementNotFound),
    }
}
```

`./src/main.rs`

```rust
use scraper::Html;
use scraping::{extract_json_1, extract_json_2, find_script};
use std::fs::read_to_string;

const FILE: &str = "./page.html";

fn main() {
    let text = read_to_string(FILE).expect("Could not read text file.");
    let html = Html::parse_document(&text);
    let json1 = extract_json_1(find_script(&html).unwrap()).unwrap();
    let json2 = extract_json_2(find_script(&html).unwrap()).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(json1, json2);
}
```

`./page.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script id="my_script">
    myJSON={"html": "HTML with a <a href=\"http://google.com/\">link</a>."};
</script>
```

`./Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "scraping"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
once_cell = "1.18.0"
rslint_parser = "0.3.1"
scraper = "0.16.0"
```

**Result**

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling scraping v0.1.0 (/home/neumann/scraping)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.64s
     Running `target/debug/scraping`
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"{\"html\": \"HTML with a &lt;a href=\\\"http://google.com/\\\"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;.\"}"`,
 right: `"{\"html\": \"HTML with a <a href=\\\"http://google.com/\\\">link</a>.\"}"`', src/main.rs:12:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am currently using the workaround in `extract_json_2()` by directly collecting the text nodes, which produces the desired output.
I am wondering if this is a good way to go or whether there's a better way to get the data I want.